# Cannot set fill color for OutlineButton

Tags: dart, flutter

The [documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/OutlineButton-class.html) for the OutlineButton says that the `color` property fills the button color and is transparent by default. Specifically the Flutter documentation says of the color property: "color → Color
The button's fill color, displayed by its Material, while it is in its default (unpressed, enabled) state."

But setting the `color` property has no effect:

```
OutlineButton(
        color: Colors.orange,
        textColor: BmsColors.primaryForegroundColor,
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: BmsColors.primaryForegroundColor, width: 2.0),
        shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius:
              new BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
        ),
        child: Text(
          this.text,
          style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Lalezar', fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
        ),
        onPressed: () {},
      );
```

[image]

Comment: But it will be filled with **orange** `color: Colors.orange` only when it's pressed. Otherwise will be transparent. If you want a filled button you can try with RaisedButton. What exactly are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Hi @Hosar, I want a gold border like I have in screenshot and a fill color of black

Comment: @Hosar, the Flutter documentation says, "color → Color
The button's fill color, displayed by its Material, while it is in its default (unpressed, enabled) state." So I believe you are incorrect Hosar, it is not only when pressed

Comment: You can do that with a **RaisedButton** combined with a **RoundedRectangleBorder**, see my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you check the source code of `OutlineButton` there is a method to get the fillColor

```
      Color _getFillColor() {
        if (widget.highlightElevation == null || widget.highlightElevation == 0.0)
          return Colors.transparent;
        final Color color = widget.color ?? Theme.of(context).canvasColor;
        final Tween<Color> colorTween = ColorTween(
          begin: color.withAlpha(0x00),
          end: color.withAlpha(0xFF),
        );
        return colorTween.evaluate(_fillAnimation);
      }
```

But this method has an `if` condition, it uses the `color` only when the `highlightElevation` is different from `0`, and also it uses the animation of the `colorTween` from `color.withAlpha(0x00)` to `color.withAlpha(0xFF)`.

So it change from transparent to your color when you press it.

You can create your own `OutlineButton` widget if you want , this a sample I made:

```
    class MyCustomOutlineButton extends StatelessWidget {
      final String text;
      final VoidCallback onPressed;
      final Color color;

      const MyCustomOutlineButton({Key key, this.text, this.onPressed, this.color})
          : super(key: key);

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.yellow, width: 2.0),
            color: color,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          ),
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
          child: RawMaterialButton(
            fillColor: color,
            elevation: 0,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 14.0),
              child: Text(
                text,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Lalezar',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    color: Colors.yellow),
              ),
            ),
            onPressed: onPressed,
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

**Usage**

```
  MyCustomOutlineButton(
            text: "Become a Member",
            color: Colors.orange,
            onPressed: () {
              print("here");
            },
          ),
```

Comment: Such a cohesive, helpful, well written code answer that I started following you on Medium and Twitter :). I am very excited about Flutter myself and really think it could a big game changer in the industry.

Comment: Why did you mark your constructor for MyCustomOutlineButton const by the way?

Comment: @BrianOgden It was generated by the IDE (VSCode) , but it's a good practice to use const when you can , specially in constructors

Answer (score 4):

For what you want, you can use a simple **RaisedButton** combined with a **RoundedRectangleBorder**. See eg:

```
Container(
            color: Colors.pink,
            child: RaisedButton(
              color: Colors.black,
              child: Text('Become a member', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow)),
              onPressed: () {
                print('Hello');
              },
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  side: BorderSide(color: Colors.yellow, width: 5.0)),
            ),
          )
```

The border color can be specified with the **BorderSide**, and the filled color is just the normal color property of RaisedButton.
Hope this help.